# Menu in iOS having some scroll issues when scrolled to the top and "bounces"

Tags: javascript, css, ios

I have a mobile menu that seems to be having some scrolling issue on iOS (safari / chrome). When a user scrolls down, a class is being added and the menu disappears. That part works. When I scroll up, the menu shows up which is correct too. However, when I scroll fast enough in iOS to reach the top, it bounces on the top edge (like the pull to refresh sort of thing), but the class is being added again as it technically scrolled down and my menu disappears.

```
    $(function() {

        var lastScrollTop = 10, delta = 60;

        $(window).scroll(function() {

            var nowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - nowScrollTop) >= delta) {

                if (nowScrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
                    $('.page__header').addClass('scroll-down');

                } else {
                    $('.page__header').removeClass('scroll-down');
                }
                lastScrollTop = nowScrollTop;
            }
        });

    });
```

There is a delta value setup to tweak the sensitivity of the scroll, but it's still not the most solid of solutions. Any advice is appreciated.